# Может быть кто-нибудь работал с конструктором запросов на Yii?

Tags: yii

Вопрос в том как написать функцию редактирования таблицы, если функция просмотра написана с помощью конструктора запросов.
`$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()` - и все такое.
Нужно создавать команду на так же конструктором только на  Update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
$command->update('tbl_user', array(
    'name'=>'Tester',
), 'id=:id', array(':id'=>1));
```

параметры метода update:
название таблицы, массив с изменяемыми полями, условие в WHERE, параметры условия

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.query-builder  Здесь подробности

Comment: Задачу решили решить через  foreach, но спасибо за Ваш ответ)